# Как в переменную записать создание папки по логину?

Tags: php

```
<?php
          if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login'];    if ($login == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим    введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то    уничтожаем переменную
          if    (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password    =='') { unset($password);} }
          //заносим введенный    пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем    переменную
          if (isset($_POST['code'])) { $code = $_POST['code']; if    ($code == '') { unset($code);} } //заносим    введенный пользователем защитный код в переменную $code, если он пустой, то    уничтожаем переменную
          if (empty($login) or empty($password)or empty($code)) //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем    ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
          {
          exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и    заполните все поля!"); //останавливаем    выполнение сценариев
          }
          function generate_code() //запускаем    функцию, генерирующую код. Можно даже вывести ее в отдельный файл.
          {
              $hours = date("H"); // час       
              $minuts = substr(date("H"), 0 ,    1);// минута 
              $mouns = date("m");    // месяц             
              $year_day = date("z"); // день в году 
              $str = $hours . $minuts . $mouns .    $year_day; //создаем строку
              $str =    md5(md5($str)); //дважды шифруем в md5
                  $str =    strrev($str);// реверс строки
                  $str =    substr($str, 3, 6); // извлекаем 6 символов,    начиная с 3
                  // Вам конечно же можно постваить другие значения, так    как, если взломщики узнают, каким именно способом это все генерируется, то в    защите не будет смысла.
              $array_mix = preg_split('//',    $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
              srand ((float)microtime()*1000000);
              shuffle ($array_mix);
                  //Тщательно перемешиваем, соль, сахар по вкусу!!!
              return implode("",    $array_mix);
          }
          function    chec_code($code) //проверяем код 
          {
              $code = trim($code);//удаляем пробелы 
              $array_mix = preg_split ('//',    generate_code(), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
              $m_code = preg_split ('//', $code, -1,    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
              $result = array_intersect ($array_mix,    $m_code);
          if    (strlen(generate_code())!=strlen($code))
          { return    FALSE;}
          if    (sizeof($result) == sizeof($array_mix))
          {   return TRUE;}
          else
          {   return FALSE;}}
          // после сравнения проверяем,    пускать ли пользователя дальше или, он сделал ошибку, и остановить скрипт
          if    (!chec_code($_POST['code']))

          {
          exit ("Вы ввели неверно код с картинки"); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев
          }
    //если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
 //удаляем лишние пробелы
    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);
    // дописываем новое********************************************

//добавляем проверку на длину логина и пароля
            if    (strlen($login) < 3 or strlen($login) > 15) {
            exit    ("Логин должен состоять не менее чем из 3 символов и не более чем из    15.");
            }
            if    (strlen($password) < 3 or strlen($password) > 15) {
            exit    ("Пароль должен состоять не менее чем из 3 символов и не более чем из    15.");
            }

if    (!empty($_POST['fupload'])) //проверяем, отправил    ли пользователь изображение
            {
            $fupload=$_POST['fupload'];    $fupload = trim($fupload); 
              if ($fupload =='' or empty($fupload)) {
                                 unset($fupload);// если переменная $fupload пуста, то удаляем ее
                                                            }
            }

         if (!isset($fupload) or empty($fupload) or $fupload =='')
{
//если переменной не существует (пользователь не отправил    изображение),то присваиваем ему заранее приготовленную картинку с надписью    "нет аватара"
$avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.jpg"; //можете    нарисовать net-avatara.jpg или взять в исходниках
}

else 
{
    $path = 'upload/'.$_SESSION['login'].'/';
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{ 
echo "Return Code: ". $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
if (file_exists($path.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{    //папка,    куда будет загружаться начальная картинка и ее сжатая копия   
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";       
}
else
{       
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);       
}

}
//иначе - загружаем изображение пользователя

$path_to_90_directory=$path;

            if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['fupload']['name']))//проверка формата исходного изображения
                      {                 
                               $filename =    $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
                               $source =    $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']; 
                               $target =    $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
                               move_uploaded_file($source,    $target);//загрузка оригинала в папку $path_to_90_directory           
         if(preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/',    $filename)) {
                     $im    = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ; //если оригинал был в формате gif, то создаем    изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
                     }
                     if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/',    $filename)) {
                     $im =    imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ;//если    оригинал был в формате png, то создаем изображение в этом же формате.    Необходимо для последующего сжатия
                     }

                     if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/',    $filename)) {
                               $im =    imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory.$filename); //если оригинал был в формате jpg, то создаем изображение в этом же    формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
                     }           
//СОЗДАНИЕ КВАДРАТНОГО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ И ЕГО ПОСЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЖАТИЕ    ВЗЯТО С САЙТА www.codenet.ru           
// Создание квадрата 90x90
            // dest - результирующее изображение 
            // w - ширина изображения 
            // ratio - коэффициент пропорциональности           
$w    = 90;  
     $w_src    = imagesx($im);

                     $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$w);

                     if    ($w_src>$h_src) 
                     imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0,
                                         round((max($w_src,$h_src)-min($w_src,$h_src))/2),
                                      0, $w, $w,    min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src));           
         // вырезаем    квадратную верхушку по y, 
                     // если фото    вертикальное (хотя можно тоже серединку) 
                     if    ($w_src<$h_src) 
                     imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0,    0, 0, $w, $w,
                                      min($w_src,$h_src),    min($w_src,$h_src));           
         // квадратная картинка    масштабируется без вырезок 
                     if ($w_src==$h_src) 
                     imagecopyresampled($dest,    $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, $w_src, $w_src);           
$date=time();    //вычисляем время в настоящий момент.
            imagejpeg($dest,    $path_to_90_directory.$date.".jpg");//сохраняем    изображение формата jpg в нужную папку, именем будет текущее время. Сделано,    чтобы у аватаров не было одинаковых имен.          
//почему именно jpg? Он занимает очень мало места + уничтожается    анимирование gif изображения, которое отвлекает пользователя. Не очень    приятно читать его комментарий, когда краем глаза замечаешь какое-то    движение.          
$avatar    = $path_to_90_directory.$date.".jpg";//заносим в переменную путь до аватара.

$delfull    = $path_to_90_directory.$filename; 
            unlink    ($delfull);//удаляем оригинал загруженного    изображения, он нам больше не нужен. Задачей было - получить миниатюру.
            }
            else 
                     {
                                //в случае    несоответствия формата, выдаем соответствующее сообщение
                     exit ("Аватар должен быть в    формате <strong>JPG,GIF или PNG</strong>");
                             }
            //конец процесса загрузки и присвоения переменной $avatar адреса    загруженной авы
            }          
$password    = md5($password);//шифруем пароль          
$password    = strrev($password);// для надежности добавим реверс          
$password    = $password."b3p6f";

            //можно добавить несколько своих символов по вкусу, например,    вписав "b3p6f". Если этот пароль будут взламывать методом подбора у    себя на сервере этой же md5,то явно ничего хорошего не выйдет. Но советую    ставить другие символы, можно в начале строки или в середине.          
//При этом необходимо увеличить длину поля password в базе.    Зашифрованный пароль может получится гораздо большего размера.          
// дописали новое********************************************  
 // подключаемся к базе
    include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 
 // проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");
    }
 // если такого нет, то сохраняем данные
    $result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,avatar) VALUES('$login','$password','$avatar')");
    // Проверяем, есть ли ошибки
    if ($result2=='TRUE')
    {
    echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на сайт. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    }
 else {
    echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$path = 'upload/'.$_SESSION['user_login'].'/';
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     }
   else{
     if (file_exists($path . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
       }
     else{
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       }
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: не выходит почемуто. заменил все под себя. мб код скинуть скажите легче на почту файлом. я нубок в этом пока очень помощь нужна)

Comment: В какой переменной хранится имя юзера?

Comment: в переменной login так я там поменял

Comment: тогда все должно работать. Загружаете файл через форму или как?
иии... там - это где?

Comment: ПРЯМО ПО СЕРЕДИНЕ ТО ЧТО МНЕ НУЖНО. КАК ВСЕГДА ГДЕТО НАЛАЖАЛ!

Comment: мб скинуть скрипт?

Comment: Добавьте основную часть логики(без хтмл) в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Найдите строку

```
$path = 'upload/'.$_SESSION['login'].'/';
```

Замените на:

```
$path = 'upload/'.$login.'/';
if (!is_dir($path) && !mkdir($path)) die('Невозможно создать папку для аватара');
```

Пока больше не вижу что заменить. Возможно, будет работать) Будут ошибки - пишите в комментарии.

Comment: Нет не хочет работать. Та же ошибка.

Comment: Помогите плс